How can we determine this conditonal distribution?
Let

$(E,\mathcal E)$ be a measurable space
$Q$ be a Markov kernel on $(E,\mathcal E)$
$(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ and $(Y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be the Metropolis-Hastings chain and proposal sequence of the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm with proposal kernel $Q$ and acceptance function $\alpha$ and $$Z_n:=(X_{n-1},Y_n)\;\;\;\text{for }n\in\mathbb N.$$

By construction, there is a $[0,1)$-valued independent identically $\mathcal U_{[0,\;1)}$-distributed process $(U_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ such that

$(U_1,\ldots,U_n)$ and $(Z_1,\ldots,Z_n)$ are independent
$$X_n=\begin{cases}Y_n&\text{, if }U_n\le\alpha(Z_n)\\ X_{n-1}&\text{, otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

Now let $\tau_0:=0$ and $$\tau_k:=\inf\{n>\tau_{k-1}:U_n\le\alpha(Z_n)\}$$ denote the time at which the $k$th proposal is accepted. Furthermore, define $$\xi_k:=\begin{cases}\tau_{k+1}-\tau_k&\text{, if }\tau_k<\infty\\0&\text{, otherwise}\end{cases}$$ and $$A_k:=\begin{cases}X_{\tau_k}&\text{, if }\tau_k<\infty\\X_{\tau_{k-1}}&\text{, otherwise.}\end{cases}$$ $(A_k)_{k\in\mathbb N}$ is the process of accepted proposals.
We can show that $\xi_k$ given $A_k$ is geometrically distributed with parameter $\varrho(A_k)$, where $$\varrho(x):=\int Q(x,{\rm d}y)\alpha(x,y)\;\;\;\text{for }x\in E.$$
Now let $k\in\mathbb N_0$ with $\tau_k<\infty$, $m\in\mathbb N$ and $i\in\{1,\ldots,m\}$. How can we compute $$\operatorname E\left[\alpha\left(Z_{\tau_k+i}\right)\mid A_k,\xi_k=m\right]=\operatorname E\left[\alpha\left(A_k,Y_{\tau_k+i}\right)\mid A_k,\xi_k=m\right]\tag1$$ for $i\in\{1,\ldots,m-1\}$?
At least intuitively, $$\operatorname P\left[Y_{\tau_k+i}\in B\mid A_k\right]=Q(A_k,B)\;\;\;\text{for all }B\in\mathcal E\tag2,$$ but I'm not even 100% about this. The problem is the additional dependence on $\tau_k$ and I'm not sure how I need to deal with the implicit dependence on $\xi_k$, since $Y_{\tau_k+i}$ is only drawn like that when $i<m=\xi_k$ ...
